# Isomorphism between the space of linear operator and matrices for finite dimensional spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, abstract-algebra

Prove that $\operatorname{Lin}(U,V)$ is isomorphic to the space of $m$ by $n$ matrices, where $\dim(U)=n$ and $\dim(V)=m$.

Thanks so much for your enlightment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Choose bases $\{u_1, ..., u_n\}$ and $\{v_1, ..., v_m\}$ of $U$ and $V$ respectively. Given a linear transformation $T \in \text{Lin}(U, V)$, can you find a matrix corresponding to $T$? (It's the same thing as the "matrix of a linear transformation.)

Comment: thx so much, it helps, but i still cannot finish the whole proof by myself. could u plz give a little more hint?